# Check a phone number with interleaving patterns

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all such patterns in a string which may be phone numbers.

A phone number pattern may be anything like `"9.1.2.3.4.5.7.8.9.0"` , `"9..1..2..3..4..5..7..8..9..0"` , `"9 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 0"` i.e string with `10` digits and interleaving patterns. I am no good with regex but I have somehow 
been able to come up with this which is far from what I want.

```
re.findall("(?=\D\d)[\d\D]{10}","for more details call 9 9 2 0 3 5 6 0 1 2")
```

**Update :**

The dots in the example i.e `"9.1.2.3.4.5.7.8.9.0"` may be any other character `"9:1:2:3:4:5:7:8:9:0"` . So I need to find interleaving elements between 10 digits.

The dots here may be anything else as I said `"9.1.2.3.4.5.7.8.9.0"` `"9$1$2$3$4$5$7$8$9$0"`

**Have come up with this now if any one can make it simpler for me:**

```
>>> import string
>>> patterns=map(lambda x : x[0] ,re.findall("((\d\D){10}|(\D\d){10})","for ... call 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0."))
>>> allnums=map(lambda x : patterns[0],filter(lambda x : (len(set(x[1]))==2 if len(x[1])==11 else False) if x[1][0]=="" or x[1][10]=="" else False ,list(enumerate(map(lambda x : re.split("["+string.digits+"]+",x),patterns)))))
>>> allnums
['1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0.']
```

Comment: What rules do you want to follow, should this match: *"I was born on 14/11/91 so I just turned 24, 11 days ago"*? Or should it only match when the exact same pattern appears between each number, in which case this wouldn't match: *"9.1..712.1.9..3..3.1"*

Comment: Replace `\D` with a blank, and check whether the remaining text has the length 10.

Comment: So the pattern may only be with similar characters interleaving between numbers and with same length. The characters may vary

Comment: Have you got solution yet?

Comment: @SIslam Still trying .

Comment: Why use `string` module- problem with my `pattern`? -Is all phone numbers start like `call 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0.` i.e. after a word `call`?  Please share all the probable text snippet where from you want to extract `phone`

Comment: No the corpus contains thousands of lines where the number may occur anywhere. I want to detect all the lines containing phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for hybrid approach

```
import re

stng = """for more details call 9 9 2 0 3 5 6 0")

sdsad 9.1.2.3.4.5.7.8.9.0


DSAKJSD2736LLS            D9$1$2$3$4$5$7$8$9$0

wdsadsad aere 9:1:2:3:4:5:7:8:9:0

9:1:2:3:4:5:7:8:9:0 qriori

9:1:2:3:4:5:7:8: qriori

3m3m3m3 sdsad 9.1.2.3.5.7.8.9.0 oqwieowqei

Final test 2..3..3 Hi  9..1..2..3..4..5..7..8..9..5"""


matches = []
for m in re.findall(r"(([\D]\d){10})|(([\D]{2}\d){10})",stng):
    match = ''.join([i for i in max(m, key=len) if i.isdigit()])
    matches.append(match)
print matches
```

Output-

```
['9123457890', '9123457890', '9123457890', '9123457890', '9123457895']
```

See LIVE <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uB2aG0/4)</kbd>.

Comment: Not the most convenient output, leaves the spaces in. Output is `[' 9 9 2 0 3 5 6 0']`

Comment: It is too close to what I want. How could I find it in this `"9..1..2..3..4..5..7..8..9..0"`

Comment: Great and I could even keep on adding for patterns of threes (([\D]{3}\d){10,}) and so on .

Comment: Yap using `|` operator

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with join:

```
 input = "for more details call 9 9 2 0 3 5 6 0"
 print ''.join([n for n in input if n.isdigit()])
```

[`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) helps to find the individual number.

Output:

```
99203560
```

Comment: Very pythonic, but makes no distinction between spaces and dots between the digits and entire sentences or words. I.e. `"..on line 13\nfor more details call 9 9 2 0 3 5 6 0"` will return `1399203560`.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer I was going to put in a similar example

Comment: `input` should always be evaluated. I think, he could work out this example based on his need. One possible solution could be execute the same logic from right to left and stop when the digit count reaches 10.

Comment: The problem is, that you'd need to separate the phone number part clearly from the rest of the text. Depending on how the text is structured, you may end up building a lot of complexity that's already present in the `re` module.

Comment: Seems like you could loop through the subsequences of 10 digits with  looking for those that have have the same character(s) between them. A simple test for the character between the 10 digits would be `len(set((character for character in characters) for characters in allCharactersBetweenDigits)) == 1` for them to all be the same character, where characters are the characters between digits. The actual code would probably be a few line function. (Note: The set should be a set of characters).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to preprecess the string to remove the dots or spaces in the middle. You'd get something like:

```
s = "for more information, call 9..1..2..3..4..5..7..8..9..0"

min_digits = 7
max_digits = 12
m = re.search ("(\d{%d,%d})" % (min_digits,max_digits), s.replace(".", "".replace(" ", ""))

print m.groups()
```

Output:

```
('9123457890',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `isdigit()` over all characters to check if they’re numbers. The code is very short:

```
newString = filter(lambda char: char.isdigit(), oldString)
```

This way your string will only be made of "numbers".

Comment: If I do this `newString = filter(lambda char: char.isdigit(), "for 123... call .1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0.")` it returns `'1231234567890'` . I would only want to get `.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0` . I need to detect patterns inside the string interleaving with numbers where a string contains a phone number. I have done it in my updated code only if it could be made simpler.